# Change width of cell using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here's the code..

```
<td align="right" width="135"> 
    <div align="right">
        <font class="class123"><b>$9.67</b></font>
    </div>
</td>
```

I have multiple instances of this cell in a table and would like to change the width of them all. I've tried things like...

```
jQuery(".class123").closest("tr").html();
```

And thought about swapping out all the html, but I don't think that's the best way. I need to do it for all the cells. Any ideas?

Comment: can you please explain more what you needed?

Comment: I need to change the "width" attr of the td cell.

Comment: $(".class123").closest("td").css('width', '500px');
you can try this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I think) this is what you want..

Change just the style - [jsFiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/fYp44/).

```
$(".class123").closest("td").css('width', '300px');
```

Or the width itself - [jsFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/fYp44/2/)

```
$(".class123").closest("td").width('400px');
```

Comment: That does add the style to the cell, but the width doesn't change.

Comment: @GeekGrid Sorry of course, I meant `$(".class123").closest("td").width('400px');`

Comment: It's not changing... I can see your solution inserts the style though... width="135" style="width: 50px;" is what happens and the width doesn't change on the browser. Maybe a parent row is screwing something up?

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if i understood... 
You want to change all td width attribute right?
Try this:

```
$('.class123').each(function(){
   $(this).closest('td').attr('width', 500);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but when doing the response this braked, so i had to edit it.

Comment: please check your code again its full of mistakes it should be `.class123`and closeing tag should be }); like this @Spacelement

Comment: @Sujaysreedhar sory about that it was fixed!

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
$(".class123").each(function(index, data){
    $(this).width("1009034823px"); //Or however large you want it.
});
```

Have a look at the doc: [jquery.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

PS: The html you provide does not have any TR-elements, so I removed that part.

Comment: Possibly you need something like: $(this).find("tr").first().width, or .closest() or whatever. Your html does not match the closest("tr") thing you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td id="myRow"></td>
 </tr>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var newWidth = $("#myRow").width();
   $("#myRow").width(newWidth*0.4);
}
```

That code change the width and may be you want this thing.